# I changed the window type of an application in KDE to "Desktop". How can I get it back?

Tags: kde

This question could be rephrased to "What is the keyboard shortcut for accessing special window option in KDE?" because I cannot access them after blocking myself out. Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open "System Settings", you can open the "Window Behavior" program and see and modify all your existing window rules in the "Window Rules" tab.